# How can I run IPA file on non-jail break iphone

Tags: iphone

I am using IPA file for testing purposes ,but some times it gives following error  "Signer not valid error" is it due to non jail break? or i have to use UDID

Comment: Where is the .ipa file from?  An SDK Ad Hoc build?  The App store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UDID of the device must be included in the .mobileprovision file associated with the app.

You can add devices through the Apple Developer Portal, and then download the .mobileprovision file. Double-click on the downloaded file to notify Xcode about it, and then Build And Archive the project again. The ipa generated from that build will now work on all of the devices you added.

Comment: but i am using another iphone4 ,error is not coming there? though i have not added iphone to Apple Developer Portal

Comment: You should not be able to run an development .ipa file on a device that is not included in the associated .mobileprovision file. Is it possible that you've signed it with a different certificate that does have that iPhone 4? Perhaps the project's provisioning file isn't the one you think it is.